# photoeditor android sdk display result image along with result image path

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, imageview

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements PermissionRequest.Response{

    public static int CAMERA_PREVIEW_RESULT = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new CameraPreviewIntent(this)
                .setExportDir(CameraPreviewIntent.Directory.DCIM, "ImgLyExample")
                .setExportPrefix("example_")
                .setEditorIntent(
                        new PhotoEditorIntent(this)
                        .setExportDir(PhotoEditorIntent.Directory.DCIM, "ImgLyExample")
                        .setExportPrefix("result_")
                        .destroySourceAfterSave(true)
                )
                .startActivityForResult(CAMERA_PREVIEW_RESULT);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, android.content.Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == CAMERA_PREVIEW_RESULT) {
            String path = data.getStringExtra(CameraPreviewActivity.RESULT_IMAGE_PATH);

            Toast.makeText(this, "Image Save on: " + path, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }
```

Hello

I want to edit the above code so that in the result the activity displays the result image along with the file path, can someone please help with this as I am very new to android development.

The github link to this sdk is-

https://github.com/imgly/imgly-sdk-android-demo

Answer (score 0):

v1 of the SDK is deprecated, please use v2 instead. Please see the documentation how to integrate the newest version. 
https://github.com/imgly/imgly-sdk-android-demo

Else I'am not sure what you actually want.
Can you please explain, how your app need to perform?